# Where are the request method constants in the Servlet API?

Tags: java, servlets

I want to write

```
if (POST.equals(req.getMethod()))
```

instead of

```
if ("POST".equals(req.getMethod()))
```

but I cannot find the constant definitions in the Servlet API (only looked in HttpServletRequest, where I expected them to be).

Where are they (I am using lots of libraries, so if someone else defines them, that would also work)?

Comment: I poked around a bit in the main Java class library a bit, too... couldn't find them as constants there either, not even in `java.net.HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: It's important to remember ~why~ hardcoding is bad. Hardcoding values can be bad for (1) readability ("Why did Bob use 3849 here?") or (2) causing bugs: when changing a value in one spot would require you to change it in another (and you only change it in one). In case 2, this value should be put in a variable/constant and changed only once. Using POST instead of "POST" does not hurt either (1) or (2), so using the "hardcoded" value is fine.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It appears that Java EE 6 added the HTTP method names as constants to the javax.ws.rs.HttpMethod annotation interface. Depending on your setup, they may be available to you.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/HttpMethod.html

Comment: Useful if you're using Jax-rs, but you're right, this is an obscure location for the constants - they probably should get moved into the Servlet api instead.

Comment: We are using java 8 + dropwizard 2. The class HttpMethod is present in jakarta.ws-api-2.1.6.jar

Answer (score 13):

As far as I know, there aren't any constants for that particular property. You can check out the [full list of constants](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/constant-values.html) to see what is available, though.

Of course, you can always define your own constants if it makes your code easier to write.

Comment: Not in javax.servlet, then. Weird that they miss the basic stuff, but have a constant of DIGEST_AUTH...

Comment: @Matt This was true when you answered but since Java 6, those constants exist. Please update :)

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I'm not really up to date on the subject anymore, if you have the new information, an edit would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

These constants are defined as private in Servlet,

```
public abstract class HttpServlet extends GenericServlet
    implements java.io.Serializable
{
    private static final String METHOD_DELETE = "DELETE";
    private static final String METHOD_HEAD = "HEAD";
    private static final String METHOD_GET = "GET";
    private static final String METHOD_OPTIONS = "OPTIONS";
    private static final String METHOD_POST = "POST";
    private static final String METHOD_PUT = "PUT";
    private static final String METHOD_TRACE = "TRACE";
...
```

It's perfectly fine just using the method name literally.

Comment: Yes, becuase typos hadrly ever happen.

Answer (score 9):

In Spring (so outside JDK, too) you can use:

```
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod
```

This is a enum which provides all HTTP Methods

So you can use `RequestMethod.POST.name()`

Answer (score 1):

Outside of the JDK, Apache Axis has a public constant for POST (but not for any of the other methods):

[org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPConstants.HEADER_POST](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/apiDocs/org/apache/axis/transport/http/HTTPConstants.html#HEADER_POST)

Answer (score 1):

If you wonder why there aren't any enums defined for this, that's explained in this question and answer: [Why HttpRequest.HttpMethod is string instead of Enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722248/why-httprequest-httpmethod-is-string-instead-of-enum)

Bottom line, the HTTP spec does not restrict the set of methods allowed, so additional methods may be used beyond those which are explicitly mentioned in the spec.

Comment: So it seems .NET has these String constants that Java lacks.