# Is there a standard constant in Java used to refer to HTTP request methods?

Tags: java, servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are the request method constants in the Servlet API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857646/where-are-the-request-method-constants-in-the-servlet-api)

I'm looking for a Java string constant to refer to HTTP request methods (GET, POST, PUT, etc.).  I expected [HttpServlet](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) or HttpServletRequest to have constants for these methods, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems not: [Where are the request method constants in the Servlet API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857646/where-are-the-request-method-constants-in-the-servlet-api)

Comment: My searches didn't turn this previous question up.  Thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 2):

In Java Spring, you can use the RequestMapping annotation to isolate different types of request methods. It is in section 13.11.3 of the following link:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-annotation

Essentially you can use these annotations to get the HTTP request method type:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
```

All the request types are in an enum in the RequestMethod object:
http://apollo89.com/java/spring-framework-2.5.3/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMethod.html