# Where to get 'http' String literal in Java?

Tags: java

To create an URL e.g. by

```
URL url = new URL("http", "localhost", "test.txt");
```

I have to use the constant String "http". Also in many other code lines. I was not able to find any constant that contains this string (or even better a constant collection of all common protocols).

Are there any existing constants for protocols?

Comment: You could create one Constants class in your project and define constants there.

Comment: Related question about the request methods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857646/where-are-the-request-method-constants-in-the-servlet-api

Comment: +1, I would also like to know if there's a generic helper class for this (such as Spring's `MediaType` or `HttpStatus`, for example)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Short Answer :

### There is no final string literal http constant in the Java SE JDK *at the time of this post.*

#### Longer Answer

I realize this is an old question but I don't think it has necessarily been answered adequately.  I believe that Leon's answer is partially correct.  Having a constant named HTTP with string value "http" is pointless in many cases.  However there are situations where this is not pointless. Additionally this question illustrates the pervasive misunderstanding of what a protocol is and is not.

#### Constant, Protocol, Scheme

There are three main reasons to use final string literals in Java.

- If you are going to use the same value in multiple places and want a single place to change the value if needed in the future.
- To avoid the use of magic numbers or their String counterparts.

The first point is self evident but not likely in this case.  The second point is applicable to the constant "http", but it depends on the usage, which I will briefly touch upon below as it relates to this example.

HTTP is an application protocol used for the transfer of hypermedia. It is one of many protocols defining how data is transferred over the world wide web (a term that is often confused with "internet").  The most recognizable aspect of the HTTP application protocol is the `http:` you see before a URI.  **However**, that `http:` you see is not the protocol, it is the scheme.  The scheme is a piece of the protocol, but is not the protocol. In that case it might be apt to have the following string literal constant.

```
final String SCHEME = "http";
```

Additionally, if you were writing some type of service client that works over multiple protocols, you might want to specify a default one.  In that case the following final string literal would be appropriate.

```
final String DEFAULT_SCHEME = "http";
```

#### Does one exist?

Indeed the following text is supported by the fact that Apache does have an http constant that is used for the reason mentioned above.

```
org.apache.http.HttpHost.DEFAULT_SCHEME_NAME
```

This constant is also included in the older httpclient library when it was part of Apache Commons (it is now part of HttpComponent).

#### Recommendation

As of Java 9 there exists no Java SE constant for http. I would favor creating your own constant instead of using Apache's.  I recommend this is because Apache's DEFAULT_SCHEME_NAME constant is specifically referring to the HttpHost class.  Utilizing it for something else violates the single purpose principal of software engineering.  To be more pragmatic, the HttpHost class could change their default scheme (maybe) without you changing your default scheme.  This would obviously be an issue.  However, Java EE does provide you with final string literals for all the HTTP methods,  response statuses, header fields, and a myriad of other HTTP-related things such as authentication types, etc. I relate with your desire to have these string literals provided as constants in Javas standard library. It would just make me feel more whole.

## Post Script

> I want to point out another usage of a final string literals that was made by user **@gorootde** in a comment below.

The example

`final String Z = "Z";`

may still have value if this result is used multiple times throughout the code base **in contrast** to other `"Z"` that are of different significance. Without knowing the context I can't judge but this would be an odd choice that would require significant justification, however it's not outright pointless by definition.

Comment: There are still reasons for using static constants missing:  E.g. preventing misspelling and making use of the autocompletion of your IDE (in the best case you use an enum or something similar to enumerate all supported protocols, so the user of your methods does not have to look up, which are supported)

Answer (score 4):

There is this constant field *http* in the Apache library:

```
org.apache.http.HttpHost.DEFAULT_SCHEME_NAME
```

If you are using this library in your application, you can use it in your case.

Comment: @L. Guthardt: The accepted answer does not even answer the question, if there is a "predefined" constant in java. This on the contrary is much more on point.

Comment: @Nils-o-mat Ah yes, you are right. I just read it completey and saw the weird thing here. I just don't know why OP accepted the answer then.

Comment: @Nils-o-mat My response most certainly does answer the question. There is no predefined constant literal http in java. That is the answer to the question., and it is the first line of my response  Additionally this answer is irrelevant because the it is not in the JSE API's

Answer (score 3):

Using the string "http" indirectly (through a constant) has absolutely no justification if it must **always** stand for a `java.String` having the value "http". It is the same as introducing an integer constant ONE as follows:

```
static final int ONE = 1;
```

However, it can be justified in the following cases:

- The name of the variable doesn't indicate that the underlying value is "http":

  `// The current value is "http", but may be changed to "ftp", "spdy"
  // or whatever better protocols will be invented in the future.
  static final String PROTOCOL = "http";`
- If it is expected that its type may need to be changed:

  `// The type of this constant is likely to be changed to org.qwerty.Protocol
  // (but it will always designate the HTTP protocol)
  static final String HTTP = "http";`
- The string is significantly longer than the introduced constant:

  `static final String HTTP = "Hypertext Transfer Protocol";`
- The value is hard to remember or understand:

  `static final int X_16KiB = 16384; // though 16*1024 could be used instead
  static final String OMEGA = "\u2126";`

Comment: I disagree with your first statement. Even the `ONE = 1` has its justification if the magic number 1 is used multiple times for expressing the same thing  (Don't Repeat Yourself!).

Comment: @k_wave: If it's for expressing the same thing, then that should be reflected in the name of the field. `ONE` is not any more informative than `1`.

Comment: As argued, ONE is problematic as it gives no new information. You go from magic number to magic constant. But repeatedly typing http is error prone, because it is not validated. If you make a typo in Constants.HTTP you will know.

Comment: @Nils-o-mat The same argument can apply to ONE vs 1 - mistyping 1 by one key to the right will result in 2 which will go undetected by the compiler and can be caught only through testing or formal verification. By using ONE instead of 1 you enable the compiler to defend you from such typos.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ReferenceUriSchemesSupported`. It provides objects that wrap default protocols (file, Http, Ftp, ...).

Answer (score -6):

Create a class Constants

```java
class Constants{
  public static final String HTTP = "http";
  // Other such constants...
}
```

And use like

```java
URL url = new URL(Constants.HTTP, "localhost", "test.txt");
```

or if there are no more constants and you want to use it in the same class then make the constant in the same class only.

Comment: My question was if there is any existing constant - I know that I can easily define one by myself.

Comment: There's no such constant, you have to define yourself.

Comment: This really misses the whole purpose of the question